# Accessing named controls from page resources

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I needed to access to the ActualWidth of a Border that didn't have a specified Width. I have been told that I can't do that on WinRT so I used a proxy from Florian-Gl (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077585/how-to-databind-control-height-to-another-controls-height)).

The thing is that I need to create that proxy on the page's resource like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <utils:ActualSizePropertyProxy Element="{Binding ElementName=noteBorder}" x:Name="proxy" />
</Page.Resources>
```

The problem is that I don't have access to that noteBorder element from the resources, but I have access to *pageRoot* that is the Page itself.

I guess that I can play with ElementName / Path to get access to noteBorder.

But there is some curious stuff:

The structure is something like:

```
Page (pageRoot) > Grid > ListView > ListView.ItemTemplate > Grid > Border (noteBorder)
```

So, If I create the proxy at the same level of the border, It won't run but If I change the ListView to a ItemsControl, it will run and works as expected.

If having it at the same level of the border I change the *ElementName* to *pageRoot* it will run at least.

So, It won't run if I put noteBorder (even when I have access to it) if I'm using a ListView, but will work on a ItemsControl, On the other hand, If I have *pageRoot* it works all ways.

So the question is: Is there a way to access *noteBorder* from resources? Or maybe a way to access it from another place but working :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an Item Template -- 
By the time you get to 
pageRoot) > Grid > ListView or Items Control

At this point in the structure, you're at the element you really want to get at, which is the container of the items that will need the border you are trying to access.

You should define an Item Template and assign the ListView's (or ItemsControl's) ItemTemplate property via binding.

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" DataContext="{Binding ToElementIfNotInheritedFromParent}" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelListBeingBoundTo}" ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={Static Resource MyCustomItemTemplate}}" />
```

Where MyCustomItemTemplate is something like

```
 <DataTemplate x:Name="MyCustomItemTemplate">
   <Border x:Name="myBorder" >
     <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstProperty}"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SecondProperty}"/>
     </StackPanel>
   </Border>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Then In your Codebehind (or if ViewModel use the code behind to pass the ListView object to the ViewModel)

```
DataTemplate dt = this.myListView.Items[indexOfChoice].ItemTemplate as DataTemplate;
Border b = dt.LoadContent() as Border;
int actualWidth = b.AcutalWidth 

OR

You can create a FindControl() method that runs recursively to extract the actual control within the border, for instance if you wanted to access one of the Textboxes.
```

The code for that is here:
    http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a612f5a6-e05e-4b68-a813-893eeda159cc

Comment: Thank you for your time. But that is not what Im asking. I need to access to a control in the resources part. I know I can pick the ActualWidth via code, but I prefer to do so on XAML, that's why I'm asking that. And my border is inside a ItemTemplate.

Comment: Ok, so once you have the Actual Width, what do you want to do? Modify some other element based on the size of the border? Modify the border element itself? 

From MSDN: Although you cannot set this property from XAML, you can base a Trigger upon its value in a style.

For More on Triggers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx

Comment: Forget about ActualWidth stuff, is just to know If I can access to a control from resources, just that.

Comment: Yes you can access the properties of a control from the resource file if the control you are accessing is Bound to a Template. In this way you can reach the properties of the control by accessing the properties of the template. Can you Modify the RunTime UI element via the Resources file? Yes using the Visual State Manager on the Template of the List Item.